# Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu-20.04

i followed the official instruction of [mongodb install_intruction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-mongodb-community-edition-using-deb-packages) on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS,
when i started mongodb by this line:
`sudo systemctl start mongod`
i got an error like this:

```
Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.
```

of course i tried to reload as mongdb instruction:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

it still shows:

```
Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.
```

then i tried:

```
systemctl list-unit-files --type=service
```

to find mongod.service but i couldnt find it. and i tried:

```
ls /lib/systemd/system
```

that didnt work either there is no mongod.service file

i really need a hand!!!

Comment: Hi Danh!

Have you searched for that specific error? Here's one result that came up: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/921753/failed-to-start-mongod-service-unit-mongod-service-not-found

Comment: i tried your link again but the first two still have the same problem. and the last one i try the second step of the official instruction ( install Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) version instead of Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic))and i got these
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-shell but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Answer (score 2):

It's too late to answer, but may be it will help someone.

In my case, if my run `ls /lib/systemd/system | grep mongo` there was no file relating to Mongo. So, I created one service file manually.

Step 1.

`sudo touch /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service`

Step 2.

Open file in vim/nano and paste below script.

```
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database Server
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/mongod
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
# file size
LimitFSIZE=infinity
# cpu time
LimitCPU=infinity
# virtual memory size
LimitAS=infinity
# open files
LimitNOFILE=64000
# processes/threads
LimitNPROC=64000
# locked memory
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
# total threads (user+kernel)
TasksMax=infinity
TasksAccounting=false

# Recommended limits for mongod as specified in
# https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-ulimit-settings

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is default service file for `mongod`. Now run `sudo systemctl start mongod`. It will hopefully work.

Comment: This got it seen, still couldn't start but that's some other issue. thanks a lot

Comment: what is your output of `sudo systemctl status mongod`

Comment: it was not started, but i fixed the other issue now it works fine. But at first the service couldn't be found, and the above fixed my issue. Thanks brother.

Comment: Welcome, Upvote and Accpet if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Do a reinstall, after purging the current installation.

```
sudo apt purge mongodb-org*
sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
```

Run the command without **sudo** for the first time

```
systemctl start mongod.service
```